# Which one of the following function types CANNOT be overloaded?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

Taken verbatim:

> Which one of the following function
>   types CANNOT be overloaded?
>
> 1. The constructor function of a structure
> 2. The constructor function of a class
> 3. The destructor function of a class
> 4. Any constant method of a class
> 5. Any static method of a class

Comment: Are you sure this is a question about Java?  There are no structures, const methods, or destructors.  I've modified the tag from "Java" to "C++".

Comment: Well, I dont think that this question is correct at all. What does they mean by saying "Constructor function of a structure" and "destructor function of a class" and "constant method" of a class. I think that's not java question or they have blindly copied it from some c++ test.

Comment: @Alex Nikolaenkov - "Taken verbatim" means "copied word for word". @Oli Charlesworth - My bad, I should have tagged it C++. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since overloading, as far as I understand it, is basically having multiple functions/methods, each with the same name but a different signature, the only logical answer would be `3.`, the destructor, since the signature is fixed to `~ClassName()`.

Answer (score 4):

The destructor

//This text in this comment is to exceed the text requirement